# .net-core Site with Partial Vue.js Frontend Form Fields

Tags: vuejs2, .net-core

I am trying to create a site that has partial implementation of Vue.js, I am looking at  using Vue.js as from what I understand it does not require a SPA site like other JS frameworks and I believe this framework ticks the boxes required.

I have a basic form that I want to be used to Create, Update and Delete objects.

The data is received via a SAL which calls an API, all Create, Update and Delete calls will go through the same API.

I have been able to do a HttpGet and HttpPost to Get and Update the data and show it on a simple form.

However when I try to display just a blank form I get the following errors:

[Error Received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj8NK.png)
The code I have is as followed:

**.cshtml page**

```
@model bms.accessbookings.com.Types.ViewModels.ShowVenueViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Venue";
}

<div  class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-wrapper">
    <div class="m-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="venueForm">
                Venue ID: <input type="text" v-model="venue.venueId" />
                <br/>
                Venue Name: <input type="text" v-model="venue.venueName" />
                <br/>
                Address: <input type="text" v- 
                             model="venue.address.addressLine1"/>
                <br/>
                Line 2: <input type="text" v- 
                             model="venue.address.addressLine2"/>
                <br/>
                City: <input type="text" v-model="venue.address.city"/>
                <button type="button" v-on:click="sendToServer" 
                     style="padding: 0; border: none; background: none; 
                     cursor: pointer;">
                     <i class="la la-save"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script src="/js/venueform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

**.cs ViewModel:**

```
public class ShowVenueViewModel
{
    public int VenueId { get; set; }
    public string VenueName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address element contains Line1, Line2, City etc

**VenueController Get and Post:**

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("GetVenue")]
    public ShowVenueViewModel GetVenue(int venueId = 0)
    {
        ShowVenueViewModel viewModel = new ShowVenueViewModel
        {
            Address = new Address()
        };

        if (venueId > 0)
        {
            viewModel = _venueImplementation.GetShowVenueViewModel(venueId);
        }

        return viewModel;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SaveVenue")]
    public ShowVenueViewModel SaveVenue([FromBody]ShowVenueViewModel venueViewModel)
    {
        return venueViewModel;
    }
```

.js page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var venueId = window.location.pathname.substring(7);

const vm = new Vue({
el: '#venueForm',
data () {
      return {
        venue: {}
    }
},
props: {
  currentevent: Object
},
  created() {
    Object.assign(this.venue, this.currentevent || {});
  },
  mounted: function() {
    axios.get('/venue/GetVenue', { params: { venueId: venueId } }).then(response => {
      this.venue = response.data;
    });
},
  methods: {
    sendToServer: function () {
      var self = this;
      console.log("Venue getting updated");

      axios.post('/venue/SaveVenue', self.venue)
        .then(response => {
          this.venue = response.data;
          console.log("Venue Updated");
        });
    }
  }
 });
});
```

At the moment if the venue has items it returns these items without a problem and displays them into the form, I can edit the inputs and "save" them which then returns the newly saved information (save functionality not yet connected to my BLL / SAL).

However when no Venue object is returned (empty) the form does not display at all, and so there is no way to enter details onto a blank form to "save" and create a new venue.

Still really new to vue.js and I find it hard to find guides that are not pointing to CLI or SPA style sites.

I may have a lot of things wrong here, but if there are any pointers to help me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well the error you're getting comes from your template (.cshtml page). You need either to make sure venue.address always has a value, or, safer, test for the presence of venue.address.addressLine1 before displaying it.

When you get an error in a render function, vue can't tell you the line number. But you know it's in the template somewhere and it's generally not hard to find. Keep your templates short :-) (the one shown is fine).

Comment: I have done that before to remove the error, adding a <div> around the address input fields with a v-if checking address.

That does remove the error.

But if I wanted to create a new venue I want to display a input field that is blank for the user to fill in, if I have this v-if the input fields is not shown at all when address is null

Comment: yup. v-model works with empty strings or null. You need to make sure that the parent 'adress' object exists though.